# How to exclude a package from a jar (with maven)

Tags: java, maven, jar, build, geronimo

I want to exclude the `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec` jar from my project, I am using maven to build the project, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019214/how-to-really-fully-exclude-a-package-from-a-jar) article and I added the `exclusion` part to my `pom.xml` but somehow after I build my project I see the `geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar` in my war file's `WEB-INF\lib`.

Please tell me how can I exclude this jar from my .war.

Comment: If it is declared as a direct dependency then you should use `<scope>provided</scope>`. If not - then you should try `mvn dependency:tree`, and find all the places where it is added.

Comment: I used `mvn dependency:tree` and found the places, what should I do now?

Comment: @Shahe "what should I do now?" It seems like [the post you've cited](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23021872). "So, your solution would be to explicitly add the core jar with an exclusion to your dependencies." to all of your dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
    <artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>


This way the maven will add them to the compilation classpath, but will not package them
```

Comment: `<scope>provided</scope>` did the job for me. Thanks